# Would James have gotten to NY some other way?

Tags: plot-explanation, james-and-the-giant-peach

In the Disney film *"James and the Giant Peach"* if James had not accidentally dropped the magical crocodile tongues on the ground, causing the peach and the insects to grow, would the tongues' magic have worked in some other way to help get him to NY?

Comment: This is just an opinion, not a definitive answer. I almost feel like it was all destined to happen the way that it did. The centipede seems to be aware of NY City, and claims to know how to get them there. The peach is also on the map. I'm not sure that there's a definite answer to this question. It's just a thought. This is a very whimsical movie with lots of little magical tidbits. The aunts are seen throughout the adventure in various places, the bow of the ship for example. It's magical, and it all centers of James' life, like the fact that NY was where his parents wanted to go.